# You must call the Connect-AzureAD cmdlet before calling any other cmdlets

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell, powershell-7.0

I get the above error when executing the sample code below. Is this related to importing with  -UseWindowsPowerShell? Any ideas or suggestions?

```
Import-Module AZ
Import-Module AzureAD -UseWindowsPowerShell
# Import-Module AzureADPreview 
Import-Module MSAL.PS 

#######################################################################################################################
# Execution starts here 
#######################################################################################################################
write-host `n"****Starting Removal Script ****"
$deploy = $false
$MSGraph = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0"
$MSGraphBeta = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta"


##############################################################################################################
# Load the settings variable from config file.
##############################################################################################################
Write-host("Loading configuration settings from file.")
$settings = Get-Content -Path ".\setupSettings.json" -ErrorAction Stop | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json
$iefConfPath = ".\setupOutput.json"
$iefConf = Get-Content -Path $iefConfPath -ErrorAction Continue | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json

Connect-AzureAD -TenantId $settings.b2cTenant

Get-AzureADMSTrustFrameworkPolicy
```

Comment: Can you share a little bit more of the error output? My guess is that your Connect-AzureAD command is failing, and therefore you aren't connected when you call Get-AzureADMSTrustFrameworkPolicy

Comment: You cannot use/access any MSOL services (Azure, Exchange, et all) without connecting to that service first.

Comment: I am connected.  The Connect-AzureAD -TenantId $settings.b2cTenant line works and I get confirmation in the terminal. I have a larger script that executes many other cmdlet but simplified down to this which gives the error in the title.  Obviously I'm doing something wrong but the connection line is literally right above it. I'm asking because the error message (in the title) is not very informative and there is very little when you search this phrase.